# Is it recommended to compute the average of metrics for classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

For computing the performance metrics of the models used for classification. Is it recommended to repeat the experiments many times (for example 10 times) and compute the average? In my case, I used 116745 samples for training and 125927 for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can try k-fold validation, where indicidual models are generated from various subsets of the data and performance measured on a validation set.

You can the compute the average and variance of model accuracy, other performance metrics to understand how stable your model is.

Comment: In my experiment, I used 116745 samples from class "C1" for training and 125927 from class "C1" and class "C2" for testing. In other words, I used the one-class classification task. In this situation, How can I use k-fold validation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but your training and testing sets should be different in each run otherwise I don't see how you can interpret the result.
As Jayaram said, the best practice is always do a [K-fold cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).